# What is the command to get mounted sdcard path

Tags: 14.04, mount, sd-card

I mounted my sd card via `udisksctl mount -b /dev/mmcblk0p1`. Is there a command which displays the path to my sd card?

Thanks guys!

Comment: From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/udisksctl.1.html: " - upon successful completion, the mount point
           will be printed to standard output."

Comment: hi muru, thank you! I was hoping that udisksctl might has a command to show me the path.

Comment: `udisksctl info` might

Comment: `udisksctl info -b  /dev/mmcblk0p1` does give the info! Thanks muru once again

Comment: Excellent, you can post that as an answer, with some example output, hopefully

Comment: you can also use `lsblk /dev/mmcblk0p1` - this only shows the mountpoint instead of the detailed output of `udisksctl info`

Comment: ur answer is top notch! I will add your reply in my answer. Thanks Zanna!

Answer (score 3):

the command `udisksctl info -b /dev/mmcblk0p1` will provide a lot of info. Under `MountPoints: /media/rolf/1190-BFD9`, it displayed the path to my sdcard.

But as Zanna pointed out, if you only need the path and not any detailed info just use `lsblk /dev/mmcblk0p1`.